# Laravel 4 Nested controllers without namespaces

Tags: routes, nested, laravel

It's possible to nest controllers into subfolders like L3?

http://paste.laravel.com/uc8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however namespaces are recommended for organizational reasons, in this case, keeping your admin functions controlled.

But if you're set on not using Namespaces, you can access it like a normal controller, but you'll need to dump the composer autoload so it can find your class. You can do that by doing

```
composer dump-autoload
or
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Comment: At the end I switched to Namespaces, after all it'll more flexible. http://paste.laravel.com/ucN

Answer (score 0):

Based on the book of Dayle Rees it should be posible if you would use instead of the . notation a slash so for example `administrator.StatisticsController@index` would be `administrator\StatisticsController@index` Laravel 4 uses the PSR-0 Loading scheme.

Comment: That would be the correct format for a controller inside a namespace.